# Updating multiple documents with elasticsearch 1.7.5

Tags: elasticsearch

Any idea how I can update multiple documents on an elasticsearch 1.7 index? 
I've seen the 2.3 documentation and it's possible with an update by query api call, but I can't update this specific instance and I can't seem to find this functionality there.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you can update multiple documents with Elasticsearch's [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-bulk.html) (refering to the 1.7. version docu).

Here you can see the difference between an normal [update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-update.html) (via curl command) and the a bulk update.

Normal update:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index1/type1/id1/_update' -d '{
    "name" : "updated John"
}
```

Bulk Update:

```
POST /_bulk
{ "update": { "_index": "index1", "_type": "type1", "_id": "id1", "_retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "doc" : {"name" : "updated John"} }
{ "update": { "_index": "index1", "_type": "type1", "_id": "id1", "_retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "doc" : {"name" : "The second update for John"} }
```

btw: Bulk requests are preferable if you have operations on many documents. here is the [docu](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/bulk.html) describing it in detail.

---

EDIT:
To update certain documents that match a query you can use the [ElasticSearch Update By Query Plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) for ES 1.7.
Btw: for newer ES versions this feature is built-in: [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

Here is an example for the syntax for the plugin:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index1/_update_by_query' -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [ 
            {
              "term": {
                "Category": "YourCategoryValueToSearchFor"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.category = \"NewCategoryValue\"; ctx._source.category2 = \"OptionallyUpdateAnotherField\";"
}'
```

To do so you additionally have to enable script's in your elasticsearch.yml config:

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
script.inline: on 
script.indexed: on
```

Comment: Hmm thanks. I found that doc. However, let's say I have a normalized document that has something like a "Category" field. And I need to update the category for all of the documents matching it. Is there any way to do that directly, without querying for them and then composing the update request from the results? I'm talking about 1.000.000+ documents, so it wouldn't be a very cheap thing to implement in php for example.